# WPF Page Fullscreen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fullscreen

I am trying to solve a problem for a quiet while now. I am using Pages in my WPF application, the code is almost done and finally I would like to make the app fullscreen.

However all the instructions and tips are for window (WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None; Page does not know these instructions)

All of my pages starts like this:

```
<Page
x:Class="WPFWiringCabinet.Views.WiringPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:controlzex="urn:controlzex"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:WPFWiringCabinet.Properties"    
d:DesignHeight="1000"
d:DesignWidth="1920"   
Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Styles.Page}"
mc:Ignorable="d">
```

Or like this

```
<Page
x:Class="WPFWiringCabinet.Views.SelectionPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:WPFWiringCabinet.Properties"
d:DesignHeight="450"
d:DesignWidth="800"
Style="{DynamicResource MahApps.Styles.Page}"
```

So I was thinking about changing the DynamicResources MahApps.Styles.Page which is like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style x:Key="MahApps.Styles.Page" TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ThemeBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ThemeForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource MahApps.Font.Size.Content}" />
</Style>
```

However this file is read only.
What I believe the WPF app should work like this: I have some window in which I am showing the pages. So I guess that I need to change the settings of that window, which I can not find. In my App.xaml I hove only following:

```
<Application
x:Class="WPFWiringCabinet.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
DispatcherUnhandledException="OnDispatcherUnhandledException"
Exit="OnExit"
Startup="OnStartup"   
>
```

I do not have big experiences with WPF apps, I used to work with forms, but I was kinda forced to use the WPF.

So my question is, how can I force the Page to be in fullscreen or did I setup the project wrong way?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

In ApplicationHostService I have this:

```
  private async Task HandleActivationAsync()
    {
        if (App.Current.Windows.OfType<IShellWindow>().Count() == 0)
        {
            // Default activation that navigates to the apps default page
            _shellWindow = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IShellWindow)) as IShellWindow;
            _navigationService.Initialize(_shellWindow.GetNavigationFrame());
            _rightPaneService.Initialize(_shellWindow.GetRightPaneFrame(), _shellWindow.GetSplitView());
            _shellWindow.ShowWindow();
            _navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(SelectionPage));
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Which I believe should work for navigation purposes and also showing the window. And the ShellWindow is define like this

```
<controls:MetroWindow
x:Class="WPFWiringCabinet.Views.ShellWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:WPFWiringCabinet.Properties"
WindowStyle="None"
WindowState="Maximized"
ShowCloseButton="False"
ShowMinButton="False"
ShowTitleBar="False"
ShowInTaskbar="False"
ShowMaxRestoreButton="False"
Loaded="OnLoaded"
Unloaded="OnUnloaded"
mc:Ignorable="d"
MinWidth="1920"
MinHeight="350"
Style="{StaticResource CustomMetroWindow}"
Title="{x:Static properties:Resources.AppDisplayName}">
```

But it looks like the instruction does not do its job.

Comment: Can you just host this page inside a WPF window and make it maximized?

Comment: The Page class encapsulates a page of content that can be navigated to and hosted by Windows Internet Explorer, NavigationWindow or Frame. It must be hosted inside something. A Page by itself does not know anything about full screen, maximized, etc. The container does know about these properties. What does your application? If it is a Windows desktop WPF application, then the use of Page is not the best approach. One advise if I may. If your experience with WPF is limited, stay away from 3rd party controls like MahApps. Learn basic WPF skills and then play with fancy controls.

Comment: Would resizing the window to be borderless and maximized meet your requirements? What exactly do you want to maximize? Are you able to bind the height and width of the page to the window?

Comment: If it was up to me I would not choose WPF page, but friend of mine chose this architecture and I have to continue in this. It looks like I do have ShellWindow that I guess I am using to show the pages (Will edit my question or put answer here, because comment can not be that long. However in the shell window I do have instruction for maximized. And what I am trying to do is if I open the App, the App would open in fullscreen mode (no taskbar)